# post output to new line of text file everytime

Tags: python, python-3.x

everytime i run my code it overwrites to first line of output.txt.
How can i make it so it writes to a new line every time?

```
def calculate_averages(input_file_name, output_file_name):
with open(input_file_name) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        name = row[0]
        these_grades = list()
        for grade in row[1:]:
            these_grades.append(int(grade))
        with open(output_file_name, 'w') as external_file:
            print(name, mean(these_grades), end='\n', file=external_file)
            external_file.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I append to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-i-append-to-a-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are reopening your file in "w" mode for each row, which will overwrite your file. You can open the file outside of the for loop to avoid this behaviour:

```
import numpy as np
import csv

def calculate_averages(input_file_name, output_file_name):
    with open(input_file_name) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        with open(output_file_name, 'w') as external_file:
            for row in reader:
                name = row[0]
                mean_of_grades = np.mean([int(x) for x in row[1:]])
                external_file.write(f"{name} {mean_of_grades}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different mode for this:

Instead of `with open(output_file_name, "w") as external_file:`,
Use `with open(output_file_name, "a") as external_file`.

"a" stands for append, which will append the text to the end of the file.

I hope I understood your question right.

Comment: This question is a clear duplicate. In such cases, flag the question as duplicate (once you have the reputation to do so) instead of providing an answer.